# random.choice() keeps returning error. I can't see the problem :(

Tags: python, random

My code is as follows:

```
import random

players = []

def player_list(new_player):
    for x in range (5):
        players.append(new_player)
    return players

for x in range (5):
    new_player = input("Please enter your player name: ")

winner=(random.choice(players))
print("You are the winner," , winner)
```

It keeps returning the following error message:

```
Please enter your player name: Rashida
Traceback (most recent call last):
 Random Role Assignment Program.py", line 11, in <module>
    mafia=(random.choice(players))
  File "C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 378, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is supposed to fill up an empty list and the return it. I checked this and it didn't work.
Then the code is supposed to randomly select a player and tell them they won.

How do I fix this?

The code may not be perfect in other aspects either.

Comment: you are not calling your player_list function

Comment: You never call `player_list` function to update your `players` list. So it is always empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre]. Here, the output doesn't match the code where you only give one input and in the traceback you have `mafia =` instead of `winner =`. Also, the traceback appears to have been doctored since `File "C:\...` is missing. That said, the same error still occurs here, but it might be for a different reason -- we have no way of knowing. Here at least, `player_list()` is never called, so `players` is never appended to, hence the error. You can [edit] if needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

players = []

for x in range(5):
    new_player = input("Please enter your player name: ")
    players.append(new_player)

winner = random.choice(players)
print("You are the winner,", winner)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you do not call the function, hence the list remains empty.

Answer (score 1):

list `players` is empty, and you can't choose a random item from empty list 
you can solve it with this

```
for x in range (5):
    new_player = input("Please enter your player name: ")
    players.append(new_player)
```

Comment: Okay. I am a beginner at this so..... Thanks a load.